# gen_server:call every X seconds

Tags: timer, erlang, gen-server

The Status of the gen_server is a list and should be processed once every X seconds. Therefore, I need to execute handle_call({process},State) every X seconds.

What is the best way to have a handle_call executed every X seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Timer” module can solve your problem. For example, In otp hehaviour implemention module,

```
init([]) ->
    timer:send_after(1000,self(),{create_log}), %<====== create an event after 1000ms
    {ok, #state{id=1}}.

handle_info({create_log},#state{id=ID})-> %<=========handle the timer event
    %io:format("handle info~n",[]),
    New_id = ID + 1,
    ls117_single_process_log:error("test log ~p~n",[New_id]),
    timer:send_after(1000,self(),{create_log}),  %<========restart timer
    {noreply,#state{id=New_id}};
```

Comment: I would recommend use `erlang:send_after/3` which has exactly same semantic but more lightweight and don't need timer server started.